# Django passing in isbn10 to url

Tags: python-3.x, django, regex

I seem to be unable to pass in isbn10 numbers in to the Django.

```
    <a href="{% url 'books-to-detail' fic.isbn %}">
      <section class="slideshow-fiction">
        <img src="{{ fic.image }}" alt="" />
        <p>{{ fic.title|truncatewords:4 }}</p>
        <!-- <p>{{ fic.description }}</p> -->
        <p>{{ fic.author }}</p>
        <!-- <p>{{ fic.isbn }}</p> -->
      </section>
    </a>
```

Examples of the numbers are 059318808X and 0316539562. I've tried to use re_path and regex however if i get one number to pass the other does not. This is one of the paths that I've tried but 0316539562 does not pass.

```
re_path(
        r"^redirect/books/(?P<isbn>[0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*[-| ][0-9]*\w)/$",
        redirect_books_to_detail,
        name="books-to-detail",
    ),
```

The error
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtoJi.png)

Trying this url path

```
re_path(
        r"^redirect/books/(?P<isbn>[\w\+%_& ]+)/$",
        redirect_books_to_detail,
        name="books-to-detail",
    ),
```

I now get an error that there is [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwohT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression part you're using to identify ISBN numbers looks a little too complex.

ISBN10 is made of 10 characters. 9 of them should be digits, and the last one can either be a digit or the `X` character. Regular expressions that represent this would be something like `\d{9}[\dX]` or `[0-9]{9}[0-9X]`

You can quickly test if this matches using the python interpreter:

```py
>>> import re

>>> re.fullmatch(r"\d{9}[\dX]", "059318808X")  # returns a match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='059318808X'>

>>> re.fullmatch(r"\d{9}[\dX]", "123X")        # does not return a match

>>> re.fullmatch(r"\d{9}[\dX]", "0316539562")  # returns a match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='0316539562'>

>>> re.fullmatch(r"\d{9}[\dX]", "03165395629999")  # does not return a match
```

So the path you're passing to `re_path` should be something like
`r"^redirect/books/(?P<isbn>\d{9}[\dX])/$"`

If you decide to accept ISBNs containing dashes, you'd need to change the regular expression to something like `(\d-?){9}[\dX]` which means we're expecting 9 digits, any of them possibly (but not obligatory) followed by a dash, and then a last digit-or-X.

Comment: I've used your suggestion but now the error is `Reverse for 'books-to-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['redirect/books/(?P<isbn>\\d{9}[\\dX])/$']`. It should be noted that the isbn from the django template are strings.

Comment: If arguments were `('',)` then it means an empty string was passed (which isn't a valid ISBN, so it couldn't be matched with the URL expression. Perhaps you should change your code from `href="{% url 'books-to-detail' fic.isbn %}"` to `{% if fic.isbn %}href="{% url 'books-to-detail' fic.isbn %}"{% endif %}` so you don't try to generate the link if the ISBN is missing (in which case the link wouldn't make much sense anyway)

Comment: Yep that did it. Turns out one of the enteries does not have an isbn10 number. Thanks